# LISP compare two lists using a loop

Tags: list, loops, common-lisp

I'm writing a simple function to loop through a pair of lists and return a true or false for each element as to whether either of the symbols is F.

This is at the end of a long string of functions and input will look as follows:

'(F E E E E F E E F F F F E E E E)
'(E F E E E E E E F F F F E E F E)

Here is how it looks at the moment.

```
    (defun finalcalc (tree1 tree2)
  (loop :for e1 :in tree1
        :for e2 :in tree2
        :nconc (if (or (eq e1 'F)
                       (eq e2 'F))
                   (print 'success))))
```

I made a mistake here. I am unsure whether it is my loop or my if statement.
It states that I attempted to take cdr of success which is not listp.

Could someone explain the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nconc` destructively concatenates the results of each iteration. `(print 'success)` prints success and evaluates to success which is not a list.

Try

```
(defun finalcalc (tree1 tree2)
  (loop :for e1 :in tree1
        :for e2 :in tree2
        :collect (if (or (eq e1 'F)
                         (eq e2 'F))
                     'success
                     'failure)))
;; print result
(mapc #'print (finalcalc '(F E E E E F E E F F F F E E E E) '(E F E E E E E E F F F F E E F E)))
; ==> (success success failure failure failure success failure failure 
;      success success success success failure failure success failure)
; (and prints the words in order)
```

Comment: Thanks! Was my mistake simply using :nconc?

Comment: @JT93 Besides not having an alternative yes. `:collect` is more common if you want to make a new list from a loop. Have a look at  [Loop for black belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) for more examples.